# xamarin forms: push notification using FCM. can't get data intent from message

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms

I use firebase push notifications, after getting push notification, need to click and get news and read it. the body of request to fcm is:

```
{
    To = "/topics/all",
    Data = new Notification
    {
        Title = news.Title,
        Body = news.Body,
        SerializedNews = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(news)
    },
}
```

the MessagingService.cs

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    private readonly string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.timelysoft.SmartClub";

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        if (!message.Data.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
            SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Title, message.GetNotification().Body, null);
        else
            SendNotification(message.Data);
    }

    private void SendNotification(IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        string title, body, serializedNews;
        data.TryGetValue("title", out title);
        data.TryGetValue("body", out body);
        data.TryGetValue("SerializedNews", out serializedNews);
        SendNotification(title, body, serializedNews);
    }

    private void SendNotification(string title, string body, string news)
    {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification Channel",
                Android.App.NotificationImportance.Default);
            notificationChannel.Description = "GGDescription";
            notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.LightColor = Color.Blue;
            notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 0, 1000, 500, 1000 });

            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        /* 
        here i put data in intent and start 
        mainactivity where I show data in new Page
        */
        mainActivityIntent.PutExtra("News", news);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 100, mainActivityIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetDefaults(-1)
            .SetWhen(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds())
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(body)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetContentInfo("info")
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.Notify(new Random().Next(), notificationBuilder.Build());

    }
}
```

mainactivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        DisplayCrashReport();

        CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        App app = new App();
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                Log.Debug("INTENT_KEY", key);
                Log.Debug("INTENT_VALUE", value);
                if (key == "News")
                {
                    if (value?.Length > 0)
                    {
                        /*
                        here code show data of comming news
                        */
                        News news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<News>(value);
                        App.MasterDetailPage.ShowPushNotificationInfo(news);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        LoadApplication(app);

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
        //App.SimSerialNumer = tm.SimSerialNumber;
        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("all");

        //Log.Debug("FIREBASETOKEN", FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token);
    }
```

if I build app and start debug everything is ok, if I get push notification first time, I can debug messagingservice.cs. and object news is ok. but if I send push notification second time, I cannot debug messaging service while getting push notification:
[no compatible code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ymlG.png)

And after that i get right push notification title and body, but news contains first sended data.
How to debug messagingservice? And why title and body fields are ok, but news object is wrong?

Comment: Did you check whether or not the received data is in the expected format, Also can you share a dummy JSON of how your data: body looks like?

Comment: If I get data first time I can debug, and check everything is ok. but if I get second push notification I can't debug it, and don't know what is inside data. but the title and body coming right. but the news object is wrong it is from first push notification. the same situation with second, third and other receiving.

Comment: Something does not feel right check this blog see if you have done something wrong https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/firebase-cloud-messaging-for-remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-xamarin-3c72fffcd25